# How can I convert array to a map?

Tags: javascript

One of the possible outputs for my service is as follows.

```
[{
    "key": 1,
    "val": 0
}, {
    "key": 2,
    "val": 0
}]
```

Is there a function that can convert this to an object like the one below?

```
{
    "1":0,
    "2":0
}
```

My purpose is to be able to read the object values as a map, such as `o["1"]`, i.e.: `if (o["1"] == 0) {...`.

Comment: Please use the search before you ask  new question.

Comment: Thanks for notifying. Probably i didn't use the right keywords to search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate over with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and assign the wanted properties with the value.

```js
var array = [{ "key": 1, "val": 0 }, { "key": 2, "val": 0 }],
    object = {};

array.forEach(function (a) {
    object[a.key] = a.val;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var data = [{"key": 1, "val": 0}, {"key": 2, "val": 0}];

var result = data.reduce((obj, e) => {
  obj[e.key]= e.val;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in javascript with

```
target = {};
source.forEach(function(e) {
   target[e.key] = e.val;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is one in pure Javascript. Maybe some library like jQuery will have something like that. You can do your own with little code, though. In pure JS:

```
var o = {};

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    o[json[i].key] = json[i].val;
}
```